# How to embed mp4 video in html for viewing in chromium on raspberry pi?

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, chromium, pi

I have a web system made in django that displays an mp4 video in an html page. I have tested this page on windows operating systems and Linux operating systems. The video displays correctly in chrome with windows when I first launch the page, however when I reload the page it no longer displays. And when I try to show the mp4 video in the chromium on a raspberry pi, it doesn't show up, it doesn't send an error, it just doesn't show up. My code to show the video is the following:

```
<video autoplay muted loop width="240" height="120">
       <source src='{{ media.mediafile.url }}'
       type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

Regards.

Comment: Maybe try a different browser on the Pi - Mozilla for example

Comment: Your browser needs the `codecs` specific for the format you are trying to play. So maybe they are missing (or not installed) from `Pi`?